# Apache Mesos failing to get slave usage. Error Slave usage

Tags: apache, mesos

Apache mesos fails to find slave usage when you select slaves on the mesos gui. Also the web console is showing "failing when trying to load resource."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common issue when running on EC2 or other cloud providers where machines have both an external and an internal IP. Mesos reports the internal IP in the UI, so if you're using the web UI from outside of EC2, the URLs won't work.

Current Mesos master and the latest 0.15 release candidate fix this issues by adding a --hostname command line option to set the hostname that gets reported in the UI.
If you're running <0.15, you can fix the issue by adding all the hosts in your Mesos cluster to /etc/hosts like so:

`<private ip> <public fqdn> <machine hostname>`

for example:

`10.98.58.170    ec2-54-224-191-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com ec2-54-224-191-136`